# Need advice for MySQL partitioning

Tags: mysql

I used table partitioning for my `users` table by `username` field.

Why I did table partitioning? Because I'd like to improve search speed by username.

- If I search by `a%`, the search speed is much faster than before partitioning.
- If I search by `%a` or `%a%`, the search speed is same as before partitioning.

The following is partitioning sql.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
...
)
(PARTITIONING users_0 VALUES LESS THAN ('a') ENGINE=InnoDB,
PARTITIONING users_1 VALUES LESS THAN ('b') ENGINE=InnoDB,
...
PARTITIONING users_25 VALUES LESS THAN ('z') ENGINE=InnoDB
)
```

- Is there any way to improve search speed by `username` field?
- When use partitioning?

Comment: for example, make an index on `username`

Comment: @mangusta, is it better than partitioning? Because I am not sure why we use partitioning on mysql.

Comment: are you planning to search that column with `LIKE` queries only?

Comment: First, the reason `a%` is faster than `%a` is because the first one is using an index (you have an index on username, right?)

Comment: if you're planning to use just a single-char prefix with (for example `a%`), partition is better than indexing because the necessary records are retrieved right away, from `less than ('b')` partition, while indexing will make several disk accesses down the index before retrieving the records

Comment: otherwise if you're planning to use more than one char in the prefix (for example `ab%`), indexing is better because you will further search within `less than ('b')` partition, especially in case if the number of words starting with `a` is much larger than `ab`

Comment: `%a` and `%a%` are very costly operations that you better avoid using frequently, because they cannot really benefit from optimizations like partitioning and indexing.

Comment: I haven't really had call to use them much, but I would expect partitions should NOT be used in place of an appropriate index. As @mangusta said, that might be good if all queries only ever query by first initial, but joining other tables to users now has to join to multiple partitions rather than one table.